# Removing a rigid body, but still getting collisions for it

Tags: c++, bulletphysics

What is the correct way to remove a rigid body, I am doing just this to remove it:

```
void removeRigidBody(btDynamicsWorld* pDynamicsWorld, btRigidBody* rb)
{
   pDynamicsWorld->removeRigidBody(rb);
   delete rb->getMotionState();
   delete rb;
}
```

However, the object still appears in `pDynamicsWorld->getCollisionObjectArray()` after I do a `pDynamicsWorld->stepSimulation`

Strangely enough this does not happen on ARM, just x86.

Comment: Could be a bug, have you asked this at the official forums?

Comment: @zeller I have not, so this is correct method as far as you know?

Comment: @zeller I've asked now: http://bulletphysics.org/Bullet/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=9129 Thanks

Comment: Ok. See my answer. Maybe it helps. LMK if not and I'll delete it.

Comment: Can't delete question, don't think it's that useful to anyone else. So feel free to vote to close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was, like most bugs just a stupid mistake. Sorry to those who took time to read it.

The error was actually in some java that called the removeRigidBody by jni.

```
if (body.id > 0) {
```

The `id` is actually an int cast of the `btRigidBody` address, so of course any `!= 0` integer could be a valid address. On the x86, the addresses happened to be < 0 which on the other device happened to be > 0.

Comment: So it really was a bug. Just not in bullet but in your code :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is what I've found. Posting code in the comments would look awful, that's why the answer instead.

```
     //remove the rigidbodies from the dynamics world and delete them
    int i;
    for (i=m_dynamicsWorld->getNumCollisionObjects()-1; i>=0 ;i--)
    {
            btCollisionObject* obj = m_dynamicsWorld->getCollisionObjectArray()[i];
            m_dynamicsWorld->removeCollisionObject( obj );
            delete obj;
    }
```

So you remove the body from the collision objects.

Comment: Thanks, I gave it a shot, but the `removeRigidBody` calls `removeCollisionObject` anyway (in `btDiscreteDynamicsWorld`), so it didn't make any difference.

Comment: I've asked someone at our local gamedev forum who uses bullet v281 and he said it's clearly not normal behavior. Though that's as far as I can help, I hope you'll get your answer at the bullet forums.

Comment: thanks for your effort, it was a stupid bug, please see my answer for details.